# Redshift COPY command for Parquet format with Snappy compression

Tags: amazon-s3, compression, amazon-redshift, parquet, snappy

I have datasets in HDFS which is in parquet format with snappy as compression codec. As far as my research goes, currently Redshift accepts only plain text, json, avro formats with gzip, lzo compression codecs.

Alternatively, i am converting the parquet format to plain text and changing the snappy codec to gzip using a Pig script.

Is there currently a way to load data directly from parquet files to Redshift?

Comment: Is there a question that you wanted to ask in the post?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I am looking for solution on processing Parquet format files to Redshift without conversion

Comment: You can use Scala and Spark to do this programatically. [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635241/can-you-copy-straight-from-parquet-s3-to-redshift-using-spark-sql-hive-presto)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to load Parquet format data directly into Redshift.

EDIT: Starting from April 19, 2017 you can use Redshift Spectrum to directly query Parquet data on S3. Therefore you can now "load" from Parquet with `INSERT INTO x SELECT * FROM parquet_data`  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-using-spectrum.html

EDIT 2: Starting from May 17, 2018 (for clusters on version 1.0.2294 or later) you can directly load Parquet and ORC files into Redshift. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-columnar.html

Comment: Can we offload data files from redshift to s3 in parquet format?

Comment: Not at the moment. Use a Glue "crawler" to convert them for you. Spectrum performance is still very good with CSV though. Use MAXFILESIZE 128MB in your UNLOAD.

Comment: How do I convert the csv files that are already sitting on S3 into Parquet format? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have a look at the Glue FAQ here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/FAQ_and_How_to.md or the example n the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-legislators.html

Comment: The [Redshift Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_command_examples-load-listing-from-parquet) here shows an example of `copy`ing parquet files, however I too recall that Redshift does not support Parquet format data.

Comment: That's a new feature that was released on the day of your comment. :)