# Can you copy straight from Parquet/S3 to Redshift using Spark SQL/Hive/Presto?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have huge amounts of server data stored in `S3` (soon to be in a `Parquet` format).  The data needs some transformation, and so it can't be a straight copy from S3.  I'll be using `Spark` to access the data, but I'm wondering if instead of manipulating it with Spark, writing back out to S3, and then copying to Redshift if I can just skip a step and run a query to pull/transform the data and then copy it straight to Redshift?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure thing, totally possible.

Scala code to read parquet (taken from [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#loading-data-programmatically))

```
val people: RDD[Person] = ... 
people.write.parquet("people.parquet")
val parquetFile = sqlContext.read.parquet("people.parquet") //data frame
```

Scala code to write to redshift (taken from [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift))

```
parquetFile.write
.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
.option("url", "jdbc:redshift://redshifthost:5439/database?user=username&password=pass")
.option("dbtable", "my_table_copy")
.option("tempdir", "s3n://path/for/temp/data")
.mode("error")
.save()
```

Comment: Any thoughts on how efficient this is in comparison to parquet -> csv -> S3 -> copy statement to redshift from S3

Comment: @marcin_koss, I haven't measured that, but generally speaking, the less transformations, the better. With S3 you also have to keep in mind possible cost of writing / reading data from it.